# Edit option visible only to the user who uploaded in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-masonry

Basically I want to add an edit option and that edit option should be visible only to the person who uploaded (just like in Facebook where edit option is visible only to that person who uploaded the story) the content, here content is uploaded by a php file (upload.php) and displayed in a masonry layout,what could be the possible solutions to it?Though i can provide user with a edit link on upload.php file  and with the help of id's assigned to each grid-item i can edit.But providing edit link on the grid itself (visible only to the person who uploaded it) would be a better idea.

```
  echo "<div class='mainlayout' data-js-module='layout'>";
                echo "<div class='grid' style='position: relative;'>";
                  include "mysql.php";
                  $query= "SELECT ID,Title,Summary,Content,ImgName,Image FROM content ORDER BY ID DESC";
                  $result=mysql_query($query,$db);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {  
echo "<div class='grid-item item1' style='position: relative; left: 240px; top: 0px; background: ".ran_col().";'>";           
 echo"<div class='show-image'>";
                        echo '<img class="image" src="data:image;base64,'.$row['Image'].' " height="240" width="210" style="border: 5px; border-radius: 5px; float:left; position:relative;"/>'; echo"</div class='show-image'>"; 
echo "<div class='content-short' style='position:relative;'>";

                            $string = $row['Content'];
                            if (strlen($string) > 200) 
                            {
                              $trimstring = substr($string, 0,200). '...';
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                              $trimstring = substr($string,0). '...';
                            }
                            echo $trimstring;
                            $id= $row['ID'];
                        echo "</div>";

                        echo "<div class='content-full'>";
                          echo $row['Content'];
  echo "</div>";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(".content-full").hide();</script>';
        echo "</div>";
                    }
                  mysql_close($db); 
                echo "</div>";
              echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Add one column "parent_id"  in table. And while inserting uploaded image add current user id in "parent_id" column. And while showing check parent id matches with current user id and then show edit link over it.

Comment: that could be one way to do it @sAcH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
See, Use session_start() for starting the session. 
So, when any user is log in, his/her Session ID will be created. OK.

And, When any user is submitting his comment, his/her ID is also submitted in database table.

So, now you are having $_SESS['Sess_ID'] & MemberID(which is inserted in database table).

Keep one if condition there.

if($_SESS['Sess_ID']==$MemberID) //Mind it, This $MemberID coming from database table where all comments are submitted. 
{
    //EDIT option (for the person who logged in when his/her $MemberID matches)
}
else
{
    // Normal Option (for Rest of the users)
}
```